# How to add item in queue with a rec function in ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

code:

```
let qrec = Queue.create ()
let q = Queue.create ()

let queueaddforto = 
  for i=1 to 5 do 
    Queue.add i q
  done

let rec queueaddrec n = 
  if n > 0 then 
    Queue.add n qrec 
  else 
    queueaddrec (n-1)

let () =
  queueaddrec 5;
  Queue.iter print_int qrec;
  queueaddforto;
  Queue.iter print_int q
```

result:

```
512345
```

It seems that can't add item in a queue sustained in a rec function. I don't know why. Is there some way to sustained add item in a queue in a rec function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no recursive calls to `queueaddrec` in the `n>0` branch of

```
let rec queueaddrec n=if n>0 then Queue.add n qrec else queueaddrec (n-1)
```

Thus when called with `n>0`, `queueaddrec n` adds exactly one element on the queue.
Note also that the line

```
 queueaddforto;
```

does nothing at all: the elements where already added to `q` at the end of the
definition of `queueaddforto`

```
let queueaddforto=for i=1 to 5 do 
 Queue.add i q
done
```

In other words, `queueaddforto` = `()` which is a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

Note that whole octachron has correctly identified the issue(s) with your code, there is no need for explicit recursion in your `queueaddrec` function to accomplish this task. The `Queue` module has a function `add_seq` which will add a sequence to a queue.

So, breaking down the problem, we need a function that will generate a sequence that counts from one number to another.

```
# let rec count_seq startv endv () = 
    if startv = endv then 
      Seq.Cons (startv, Seq.empty)
    else if startv > endv then 
      Seq.Cons (startv, count_seq (startv - 1) endv)
    else 
      Seq.Cons (startv, count_seq (startv + 1) endv);;
val count_seq : int -> int -> int Seq.t = <fun>
# count_seq 1 5 |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

You just need to use this function to generate a sequence that you can add to your queue.

```
# let qrec = Queue.create ();;
val qrec : '_weak5 Queue.t = <abstr>
# let queueaddrec n = 
    count_seq n 1 
    |> Queue.add_seq qrec;;  
val queueaddrec : int -> unit = <fun>
# Queue.add 5 qrec;;
- : unit = ()
# queueaddrec 5;;
- : unit = ()
# Queue.to_seq qrec |> List.of_seq;;
- : int list = [5; 5; 4; 3; 2; 1]
```